# Formatting Copy/paste charts in VBA

Tags: vba, charts

Currently, I have some code that copy pastes some graphs over to a newly created sheet and then turns that sheet into a pdf. However, if the graphs extend beyond one page, the graph is cutoff in the middle between the two pages. How do I ensure that this does not happen? Should I create a template specifically to copy/paste these graphs onto?

Here is the part that copy/pastes the graphs over.

```
 x = 1
    y = 1
    For i = 1 To source.ChartObjects.Count
            title_name = source.ChartObjects(i).Chart.ChartTitle.Text

            If InStr(Replace(title_name, ",", ""), search) > 0 Then

                source.ChartObjects(i).Activate
                ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

                wsTemp.Cells(x, y).PasteSpecial
                x = x + 20


            End If

        Next
Next

        wsTemp.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=NewFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
               IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
        wsTemp.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
LetsContinue:
        With Application
            .ScreenUpdating = True
            .DisplayAlerts = True
        End With
        Exit Sub
Whoa:
        MsgBox Err.Description
        Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the procedure used to create the PDF. If it is taking the PrintArea of the worksheet and converting it then you could do this

1. When pasting the graph you should also set the print area to cover the width of the graph.
Something along the lines of this:

```
rngPrintArea = Range(wsTemp.cells(1,1), wsTemp.cells(x, y + 1))
wsTemp.PageSetup.PrintArea = rngPrintArea.Address
```

2. If this issue isn't with the PrintArea on the spreadsheet and is
occurring because the width of the graph is just bigger than the
fixed size allotted for 1 page when using the PDF procedure then you
need to decrease the size of the pasted graph.

```
ActiveChart.Width = 10 ' Change 10 to whatever width is acceptable for the PDF procedure
ActiveChart.Heigth = 10 ' Change 10 to whatever height is acceptable for the PDF procedure
```

Comment: Archias, This only happens when I paste multiple graphs. One graph will be fine but then the second graph will be cut in the middle between two pages.